# What's wrong with my while loop program? (java) it's supposed to end when it reaches -6000

Tags: java, while-loop

I coded this little program to learn while loops. What I want it to do is decrease X and print it until it reaches -6000, then terminate the program, but apparently there's something wrong with my code, here it is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 3;
    int y = 20;
    int z = -6000;

    while(x != y){
        System.out.println(x);
        {x++;}

        while(x != y){
            x--;
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        while(x == z){
            System.exit(0);
            System.out.print("counted to 6000");
        }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is that `y != z`. On exiting the second `while` loop, `x` will become the same value as `y` because of the loop condition.

Comment: `while(x != y){` should probably be `while(x != z){`

Comment: One more problem is that `x < y` for initializing, which will tale too long time to become `x` become the same value as `y` by repeating `x--;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the merit of the inner while loops for the problem you described. Why not just do:

```
int x = 3;
int z = -6000;

while(x > z){
    System.out.println(x);
    x--;
    }
System.out.print("Counted to 6000");
System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

> What I want it to do is decrease X and print it until it reaches -6000, then terminate the program.

If you just want to do that you only need 1 `while` loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 3;
    int z = -6000;

    while(x != z){
        x--;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    System.out.print("counted to -6000");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your brackets your second while loop should enclose the last while loop and if you want your System.out.print("counted to 6000"); statement to do anything you need to put it before you call System.exit(0);

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's happening as we step through the code:
Before entering first while: x=3, y=20, z=-6000.

- Enter first while loop, increment x to x=4
- Enter second while loop, this will loop indefinitely because x will never be equal to y. x starts at 4 and decrements with each loop.

Since you asked what's wrong with the code I'll finish answer here. It will be a valuable learning experience for you to figure out how to change the code to get the behaviour you expect.